# I am struck with Error CS0246:The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: mysql, asp.net, nuget-package, mysql.data

I am getting the error(Error CS0246:The type or namespace name 'MySql' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). So I tried installing MySql.Data NuGet Package in my ASP.NET project. But when I tried using Tools > NuGet Package manager > Manage NuGet packages for solution option to install it I can't find the MySql.Data since it says no result found. Then I tried Package manager Console to install MySql.Data by using the "Install-Package" command and also tried to update and reinstall every package using "Update-Package". But I had no luck can someone help me with this.

Comment: try the comand from here https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the code segment that's causing this error.

Comment: Compare the version of the assembly in web.config and .csproj and delete .vs folder

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.